# LG G Flex navigation buttons problem

Tags: lg, touch, lagging

A couple days ago I noticed a problem who is starting to frustrate me.
My LG G Flex (LG-D958) is having laggy navigation buttons. 
If I open text messages, and my keyboard pops out to write, if I click "Home" button it wont react. It's the same with other two buttons "Back" and "Properties".
I tried to click it multiple times in a row, but nothing. But after i get out from the messages or any application where I need to use keyboard(viber,whatsapp), it's still almost the same. I also tried on the home screen clicking the home button for multiple times and it only reacts on only second-third click.
There are no dead pixels or any kid of problems on the display, the touch on any other part of the display is fine and works correctly.
Android version 4.4.2

**Update 2#**
I downloaded MultiTouch tester on Google Play, and by what I see the display is okay, but I cant test the navigation buttons...

**Update 3**

Okay, Ia managed to test the touch where the buttons are. I hid them and then started the application for multi-touch testing. And it seems that the touch doesn't react on a small part of the display where the nav. buttons are.Below is the picture of the phone. If i got more down the touch signs will disappear.

[image: phone screen]

Comment: I am not sure if this can be a solution for you but it is worth a try right? Go to the "developer options" inside your settings app. If it is not listed there, go to "about the phone" and click 7 or more times on the entry "buildnumber". Now go back and head to the devoloper options. Under the subcategory "Input" there should be an option that touch gestures on the status and nav bar should be ignored by apps. Try disabling/enabling it and see if it makes a difference. I hope it does.

Comment: In input subcategory is only "Show touches" and "Show touch data" options